# When I execute ASP.net app in 64 bit , I am getting compilation error in Asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I execute ASP.net app in 64 bit mode , I am getting compilation error in  Asp.net app. If I execute ASP.net app in 32 bit mode , it work proper.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'GlobalInternals' does not
>   exist in the current context

GlobalInternals is class.This class present in class library project .I added class library project dll in Asp.net project.

Please give me suggestion.How i can solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that the assembly `GlobalInternals` is configured for 64bit cpu.

> You can go to `GlobalInternals` -> right click and select "Properties"
>
> In properties page select "Build" tab and check the "Platform" option.

If there is 64 bit dll present then reference the right dll